# Entity Framework (.net 3.5) Auto Generated class wont display (SQL Server) tables properties in code

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Can anyone help me understand why I can't get the auto generated classes properties and methods I would expect from initializing the class?  Pictures and code example below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you have yet another `PortfolioGallery` class, a web page or a web control perhaps?

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid :( I do have a webpage named PortfolioGallery.  Thank you so much for the help.  If you make that the answer I will mark it as the answer.  THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you have yet another `PortfolioGallery` class, a web page or a web control perhaps?

(this is a correct answer as stated by the original poster)